# Is there any way in Tomodachi Life to force people to date?

Tags: tomodachi-life

I was wondering if there was a way to force Miis in Tomodachi Life to date. I have tried making them friends and sending them on trips, but it does nothing!

Answer (score 2):

From what I've seen, aside from telling a mii to either go for it or back off, there's no way to influence relationships.

Answer (score -1):

You can't, you have to wait until a Mii shows feelings for another Mii.

Comment: Hi @Melanie, can you provide a source for this information? it is always better to included your source even if it is from your own experience playing the game.

Comment: My experience..

Answer (score -1):

What I have done is, let's say you want Jade to date Mark. I would leave them, alone and date/get married to whomever they choose. Let's say Jade gets married to Samuel and Mark gets married to Kayla. I would switch Kayla and Jades looks and personalitys so it would be what I wanted. Now it looks like Jade is married to Mark which is what was wanted. The skill levels would be different though.